# User input control

Tags: user-interface

I am writing script, basically it's a calculator for very specific industrial procedure. ***I want to block alphanumeric input and allow only numerical input. How I do that????***
I have used variable for user input but ***I want to restrict user to numerical input only,*** since it is a calculator.

For example:

cp=0

echo -n "Please Enter count % "

read cp

Comment: read the input in a loop.  check that it's numeric.  if not, print an error and return to the start of the loop.  if it is numeric, continue with the rest of the script.

Comment: e.g. a very simple version might look like: `numeric=0; while [ $numeric -eq 0 ] ; do read -p "Please enter count % " cp ; if [[ $cp =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then numeric=1 ; else echo "Error: enter numeric value only" ; fi ; done`

Comment: Dear Sir,               Thats wonderful.......... it gives me some more creative and interactive ideas. I have just checked your prescribed solution and it works owsam. Very much appreciated Sir.......... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

Read the input in a loop. Check that it's numeric. If not, print an error and return to the start of the loop. If it is numeric, continue with the rest of the script.

Here's a very simple implementation of that algorithm:

```sh
numeric=0
while [ $numeric -eq 0 ] ; do
  read -p "Please enter count % " cp
  if [[ $cp =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    numeric=1
  else
    echo "Error: enter numeric value only"
  fi
done
```